# Bower Install of arcgis-js-api failing (unable to find suitable version for dojo)

Tags: javascript, dojo, bower, arcgis-js-api

I get the following error when trying to run the following command: `bower install arcgis-js-api`

I've tried installing into a new directory and also after creating a base bower.json file. Searching the web has found some people with the issue, but no posted solutions on how to resolve.

```
{  
    "name": "arcgis-js-api-sample-app",  
    "version": "1.0.0",  
    "license": "Apache-2.0",  
    "dependencies": {  
        "esri": "arcgis-js-api#3.15.0"  
    },  
    "resolutions": {  
        "dojo": "v1.10.4/esri-3.14.0"  
    }  
}
```

Error Message:
bower install arcgis-js-api  ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for dojo

Full Trace:

```
$ bower install arcgis-js-api
bower arcgis-js-api#*           cached https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-js-api.git#4.3.1
bower arcgis-js-api#*         validate 4.3.1 against https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-js-api.git#*
bower dojo#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0  cached https://github.com/Esri/dojo.git#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0
bower dojo#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0         validate v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0 against https://github.com/Esri/dojo.git#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0
bower util#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0           cached https://github.com/Esri/dojo-util.git#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0
bower util#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0         validate v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0 against https://github.com/Esri/dojo-util.git#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0
bower dojox#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0          cached https://github.com/Esri/dojox.git#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0
bower dojox#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0        validate v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0 against https://github.com/Esri/dojox.git#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0
bower dgrid#v1.1.0/esri-3.20.0           cached https://github.com/Esri/dgrid.git#v1.1.0/esri-3.20.0
bower dgrid#v1.1.0/esri-3.20.0         validate v1.1.0/esri-3.20.0 against https://github.com/Esri/dgrid.git#v1.1.0/esri-3.20.0
bower dijit#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0          cached https://github.com/Esri/dijit.git#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0
bower dijit#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0        validate v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0 against https://github.com/Esri/dijit.git#v1.12.1/esri-3.20.0
bower dstore#1.1.1                       cached https://github.com/SitePen/dstore.git#1.1.1
bower dstore#1.1.1                     validate 1.1.1 against https://github.com/SitePen/dstore.git#1.1.1
bower moment#2.17.1                      cached https://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.17.1
bower moment#2.17.1                    validate 2.17.1 against https://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.17.1
bower dojo#>=1.8.9                       cached https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#1.12.2
bower dojo#>=1.8.9                     validate 1.12.2 against https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#>=1.8.9
bower dijit#1.12.1                       cached https://github.com/dojo/dijit.git#1.12.1
bower dijit#1.12.1                     validate 1.12.1 against https://github.com/dojo/dijit.git#1.12.1
bower dojox#1.12.1                       cached https://github.com/dojo/dojox.git#1.12.1
bower dojox#1.12.1                     validate 1.12.1 against https://github.com/dojo/dojox.git#1.12.1
bower dojo-themes#1.12.1                 cached https://github.com/dojo/themes.git#1.12.1
bower dojo-themes#1.12.1               validate 1.12.1 against https://github.com/dojo/themes.git#1.12.1
bower dojo#>=1.8.1                       cached https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#1.12.2
bower dojo#>=1.8.1                     validate 1.12.2 against https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#>=1.8.1
bower dojo#1.12.1                        cached https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#1.12.1
bower dojo#1.12.1                      validate 1.12.1 against https://github.com/dojo/dojo.git#1.12.1
bower                                 ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for dojo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. This seems to be a problem on windows machines when using the gitBash interfaces. gitBash isn't allowing for user interaction to respond to prompts for selecting specific versions of the dependencies and just shows the error message.

I switched to using the gitCMD prompt instead of gitBash. Once switching to gitCMD and running the same `bower install arcgis-js-api` command, the questions on selecting the dependencies showed up and I was able to successfully select them and finish the install.

I hope this helps anyone else using bower on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to reproduce this issue. If I do just `bower install arcgis-js-api` I'm given the option to choose my resolutions. If I use the `bower.json` you posted, I get a warning, but no error.

`Please note that, esri#3.15.0 depends on
  dojo#v1.10.4/esri-3.14.0 which resolved to dojo#v1.10.4/esri-3.14.0
  dstore#1.1.0 depends on dojo#>=1.8.1 which resolved to dojo#1.12.2
Resort to using dojo#v1.10.4/esri-3.14.0 which resolved to dojo#v1.10.4/esri-3.14.0
Code incompatibilities may occur.`

That's fine, it's just Bower giving a warning to play it safe.

Have you tried `bower cache clean`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I hadn't tried bower cache clean but looks like it was a separate issue and I was able to find a solution that I just posted.